# Reliable data sources of 1,2,3,5,10,30,60,320 minute S&P500 O,H,L,C,V data

Tags: time-series, futures, index

I am looking for a reliable data source provider for 1 to 320 minute S&P500 data. Or the ES mini contract.

Can anyone suggest a good source for this?

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

Good list of reviewed data sources from Caltech (includes Tickdata.com mentioned in previous posts).

http://quant.caltech.edu/historical-stock-data.html#

Answer (score 1):

I get this data (both the index and the Eminis) from TICKDATA.COM (I am not affiliated with this company). Reliable and high quality. I am sure there are many many satisfactory other sources.